# System path does not extend to all accounts?

Tags: windows-server-2003, apache-2.2, path

In Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables, the PATH variable in the bottom part (the system, not just my profile) contains my perl path.  Yet when I try to run system('perl ...') from a mod_perl2 script, it can't find the executable.

How come the system path variable doesn't affect all accounts, particularly the one Apache runs under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the account Apache runs under, its PATH does not contain '%PATH%' in order to preserve its inheritance from the whole system's PATH.

Comment: Is that how HKEY_USERS\S-1-3-18-1060284298-8856024091-725778743-9376\Environment is merged?

Comment: In fact, the account doesn't appear to have a Path key under Environment.  At least, from perl backticks it says, "PATH=(null)".  Now to find out which of these random S-n-n-... users is the right one...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging out and in again or restarting the service after you made the change?  The PATH is copied when a user logs in, or a service is started.

Comment: Yes, the whole machine has been restarted multiple times since then.